# Sql where Condition execution not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query logic

1. Show comments which is not deleted
2. Show comments which is deleted after created, within a timespan of 30 days before today(Today - Createddate <= 30)

Below is the logic which I wrote, but I don't think it is working correct.

```
SELECT string_agg(
    CAST(CONCAT_WS(',',
     c.Id,
     COALESCE(c.ParentCommentId, 0),
     c.TotalRatingsCount,
     c.Pinned,
     c.IsDeleted,
     FORMAT(c.CreatedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
 , '|')
FROM Comments c
WHERE c.DiscussionId = d.Id
and                             
((c.IsDeleted = 0 and DATEDIFF(day, c.CreatedDate , GETDATE()) >= 30))
or
(((c.IsDeleted = 1 or c.IsDeleted =0) and DATEDIFF(day, c.CreatedDate , GETDATE()) <= 30))
```

Comment: Why don't you think it's working correctly? If you're not sure, how can we be, when we can't run the statements?

Comment: Also, those `WHERE` clauses aren't SARGable. Don't use functions against your columns in the `WHERE`.

Comment: condition1 and co dition2 or condition3 is the current statement. Do you want this? If not- count the brackets. Or add additional pair. Just to be sure how it is evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT string_agg(
    CAST(CONCAT_WS(',',
     c.Id,
     COALESCE(c.ParentCommentId, 0),
     c.TotalRatingsCount,
     c.Pinned,
     c.IsDeleted,
     FORMAT(c.CreatedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
 , '|')
FROM Comments c
WHERE c.DiscussionId = d.Id
and                             
((c.IsDeleted = 0 )
or
((c.IsDeleted = 1 ) and DATEDIFF(day, c.CreatedDate , GETDATE()) <= 30))
```